# How to get data of invisible rows in scrolled listview?

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

I have a listview with EditTexts and a Button in the bottom of listview. The list is long and it scrolls.

I want to get the content of all EditTexts when the Button is clicked. I used from `getItemAtposition(position)` for geting data of rows, but it just get the visible rows!

I tried `getchildAt(position)` too!

Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it that way.

ListView only renders/shows the views that are in the visible scrolled area. Any view getting out of view range gets reused by the model in view range.

It means you will have to catch some events, for example when a TextView is losing focus then you should get it's content before the user scrolls it out of view range.

If you have a limited number of rows you may consider using a vertical layout instead, where all child views will be persistent.

Comment: So how can i get data of all EditTexes!?

Comment: Didn't I just say "no" ? If you read my answer carefully I say that there aren't "all EditTexts" to begin with. They just don't exist. If you list has 100 childs but only 5 are shown there's no need to create more than 5 EditTexts.